# Run-time error '1004' when attempting to insert date

Tags: excel, vba

I have this script, I keep getting an error: `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object _'Worksheet' failed`

Here is the script:

```
Option Explicit
    Sub ONJL()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsRD As Worksheet 'Raw Data

    Set wsRD = Sheets("Raw Data")

        With wsRD
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            lastrow = wsRD.Range("J:J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsRD.Range("J" & lastrow).Value = "=Today()"
        End With

    End Sub
```

I thought this is how  you are meant to look up last row, and then paste today's date on the last cell?

Comment: In your statement assigning `lastrow`, your range seems strange to me. I've seen usage of this function before and the calls appear more like this: `Sheet.Range("A656")`. Perhaps it's confused because you're giving 2 column values as the range?

Comment: see this on how to get the lastrow correctly. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

- when you use `with`, you need to reference the object with `.`
- the result of `Offset(x,y)` is a range, not a number - you are interested in the row, so you need to add `.Row`
- the `End(xlUp)` thingy has to start from the last row to work

This is probably what you meant:

```
Sub ONJL()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsRD As Worksheet 'Raw Data

    Set wsRD = Sheets("Raw Data")

    With wsRD
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        lastrow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("J" & lastrow + 1).Formula = "=Today()"
    End With

End Sub
```

And don't forget to turn the screenupdating on somewhere.

Comment: +1 but I think it should be `.Formula`, not `.Value`. Or you could put `.Value = Date` if the OP wanted a static date instead of a formula.

Comment: I have screen updating further down the script... but I hate to say this, but the script isn't updating anything. It runs without errors, but the cell in question isn't populated with today's date. Help please?

Comment: If I create a new workbook, rename a tab to "Raw Data", populate some random data in column J and run the macro in my answer, it populates the date in the first available row. Either you mistyped the code or your problem comes from another place in your code.

Comment: @MattRidge It worked for me, the same as the code in my answer.

Comment: @MattRidge Have you tried to run your code in debug mode (line by line) to see what goes wrong? (And remove the sreenupdating thing when you debug to make sure you do see the changes!)

Comment: What is the value of lastrow?

Comment: That's what your original code would give. Are you sure you are using the code in my answer?

Comment: `lastrow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Yes, I just placed your code into mine, and I am still getting 0, and I am running this step by step (F8)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13627/discussion-between-assylias-and-matt-ridge)

Comment: It's been solved, partly was my computer having a hissyfit, but this works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 2):

`lastrow` is declared as a Long variable, but `Offset` returns a `Range` object. The `Row` Property gives you the numeric value of the row.

```
Sub ONJL()

  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim wsRD As Worksheet  'Raw Data

  Set wsRD = Sheets("Raw Data")

  With wsRD
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    .Range("J" & lastrow).Formula = "=Today()"
  End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't update the cell in J... it doesn't even overwrite anything either. I've tried this script, and it runs, it just shows no output... help please?

Comment: Tested and it worked for me. Every time I run it, it puts the formula into the next available cell in column J. Do you have calculation set to Manual?

Comment: Auto, because the screenupdating = True after the end of the script.

Comment: I wasn't aware that changing the `ScreenUpdating` Property also changes Calculation mode.

Comment: Me neither just stating that I do have it correct itself at the end.

Comment: Just tried it (again). I did the same thing [assylias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398230/run-time-error-1004-when-attempting-to-insert-date/11398838#comment15029537_11398411) did and it worked.

Comment: ScreenUpdating is not related to the calculation mode.